# how to move an objects in the array after changing key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array with objects sorted by key 'order'

```
[
  {order: 1, id: 1, title: elem1},
  {order: 2, id: 2, title: elem2},
  {order: 3, id: 3, title: elem3},
  {order: 4, id: 4, title: elem4},
  {order: 5, id: 5, title: elem5}
]
```

after change key 'order' in 'elem2' to '4', array should look like this

```
[
  {order: 1, id: 1, title: elem1},  
  {order: 2, id: 3, title: elem3},
  {order: 3, id: 4, title: elem4},
  {order: 4, id: 2, title: elem2},
  {order: 5, id: 5, title: elem5}
]
```

I wanna move an objects in the array after changing key 'order' in some object in both direction

Comment: Array.prototype.sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: @Vld - It's more an 'extract' and 'insert back' operation. Item #3 is moving as well. Not sure how this could be done with a sort.

Comment: @Arnauld By sorting-that's what sorting does, it arranges elements by default or specified rules.

Comment: @Arnauld seriously, dude? What sorting does is that it _sorts stuff_. `objects.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)`. This complex and incomprehensible solution took me 5 seconds to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function:

```
var elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4, elem5;
var arr = [
  {order: 1, id: 1, title: elem1},
  {order: 2, id: 2, title: elem2},
  {order: 3, id: 3, title: elem3},
  {order: 4, id: 4, title: elem4},
  {order: 5, id: 5, title: elem5}
];

arr[1].order = 4;
arr[3].order = 2;

arr.sort((a, b) => a.order > b.order);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.splice()` to move the item and `.forEach()` to update the `order` property.

```js
var arr = [
  {order: 1, id: 1, title: 'elem1'},
  {order: 2, id: 2, title: 'elem2'},
  {order: 3, id: 3, title: 'elem3'},
  {order: 4, id: 4, title: 'elem4'},
  {order: 5, id: 5, title: 'elem5'}
];

function moveItem(arr, from, to) {
  arr.splice(to - 1, 0, arr.splice(from - 1, 1)[0]);
  arr.forEach(function(e, i) { e.order = i + 1; });
}

moveItem(arr, 2, 4);

// formatted output
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr).split('},').join('},\n'));
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just supply a sort function that compares the order property value of each element? I mean, your approach seems very brittle and unnecessary, no? And there's a working example from an hour ago.

Comment: @DaveNewton I may be missing something here, but I still don't get it. By just sorting (like the other answer does), item #3 will remain at the same position. This is _not_ what the OP wants.

Comment: In fairness to you it's not clear what the OP expects if two order values are the same.

Comment: @DaveNewton My understanding is that the OP wants to move element A at position B, shifting all elements between A and B towards the beginning of the array, then update the 'order' properties to reflect the new arrangement.

Comment: (or shifting towards the end of the array when B is before A)

Comment: `function moveItem(arr, from, to) { arr[from].order = to; arr[to].order = from; arr.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)}`

Comment: @Vld Sorry to insist, but this is not doing what the OP wants. I apparently failed to explain that, but please have a closer look at the desired output.